# PHP Post Automatic login Login

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I need to parse a page that is protected by email.
If I directly insert the url of the page that I have to parse, the system automaticaly redirect on the login page.
The login page has a post form, and obviously I have the username and password to login.
But what's the way to post my username and password to be redirect to the correct page to parse?
I've already  tryed to post the credentials through 'curl' but a when I go to parse it always get the login page .
Thank you guys!

Comment: You need to mimic what the original login form does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are on the site you log in and after that you go to the page you want. The site allows you to get there because they usually have a session where they store your data. So basically you need to mimic a session in your system based on cURL.

If you think how a session works you realize that you most likely need to accept a cookie where the site will store the session id. So this is also what you need to do with cURL. You need to give it a way to store cookies.

So you can use the [curl_setopt](http://php.net/curl_setopt) function like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/path/to/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/path/to/cookie.txt');
```

Your script needs permissions to write in that file. And after that the only thing you need is to use the same cookie file for two consecutive calls: one to the login page and one to the page you need to parse.